# add image with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I add all images inside a folder to a div using jquery? and then is it possible that when I click on a link to change the folder, delete all current images and then add the new ones from the new folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has the same rights as JavaScript to access the file system in a browser environment - **none**.

The sane way would be to have some server side code hand an array to your JavaScript.

The **utterly insane** way would be to name your images `\d.jpg` and have JavaScript request them until it 404s. This is so bad, you should never do it. I'm just mentioning this to say it is possible.

Comment: i can give all the adresses of the images i want, how do i then add them with jquery and then remove them?

Comment: @Brandon I think that is covered in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Bogdan Iterate through the list, creating `img` elements and setting their `src` attribute accordingly.

Comment: and to remove the img created what should i use?

Comment: @Bogdan Use a selector to find the relevant image, and then use `remove()` to remove it from the DOM, or `hide()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this entirely with jquery.  You would need an intermediary script on the server that would accept requests for a list of images in a given directory, and then return that information to the client, which you could from there easily do what you want.